# Getting error Uncaught Error: Cell type must be a string while trying to add renderer in a cell Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I have a situation where I have to add different renderer in a cells based on few conditions. So solve this I have done following steps;

```
makeHighlight(rowNum,colNum, highlightFor = '')
{
  var root = this;
  handsOnTable.updateSettings({
        cells: function (row, col) {

            var cellProperties = {};

            //if for row never cell property set means 
            sheetConfig.cellProperties[row] == undefined
            if(sheetConfig.cellProperties[row] == undefined)
                sheetConfig.cellProperties[row] = [];

            //If row number and column number matches
            if (row == rowNum && col == colNum) {

                if(highlightFor == 'condition1')
                {
                    cellProperties = {
                        type : {
                            renderer : root.renderer1
                        }
                    }
                    sheetConfig.cellProperties[row][col] = cellProperties;
                }
                if(highlightFor == 'condition2')
                {
                    cellProperties = {
                        type : {
                            renderer : root.renderer2
                        }
                    }
                    sheetConfig.cellProperties[row][col] = cellProperties;
                }
                if(highlightFor == 'condition3')
                {
                    cellProperties = {
                        type : {
                            renderer : root.renderer3
                        }
                    }
                    sheetConfig.cellProperties[row][col] = cellProperties;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(sheetConfig.cellProperties[row][col] != undefined)
                {
                    cellProperties = sheetConfig.cellProperties[row][col];
                }
            }
            return cellProperties;
        }
    });
 }
```

Now my renderer functions are;

```
renderer1(instance, td, row, col, prop, value,cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);   
    //td.style.background = '#ffff00';
    td.style.background = '#ffff0091';
};

renderer2(instance, td, row, col, prop, value,cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);   
    td.style.background = '#FF9999';
};

renderer3(instance, td, row, col, prop, value,cellProperties) 
{
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);   
    td.style.background = '#FFFF33';
};
```

Now issue is I am getting an error as;

**Uncaught Error: Cell type must be a string**

Can you please help me out what I am doing wrong? I am trying to figure it out but still no luck.

Any help will be great for me.

Thanks in advance.